# Swift get tailing subarray

Tags: arrays, swift

Swift's implementation of arrays is throwing me for a loop again! (Haw, haw.) All I want is to take an array of arbitrary length and get a new array (or an array slice) from it that has the first element removed.

Why is this so hard?

I just want to be able to do something like this:

```
let suffix = someArray.suffixFrom(1)
```

But I can't figure out how to do this. It seems the closest method I've found requires knowing the length of the array, which I don't know because it's computed inline and I really really hate having to split such a simple concept up into a bunch of variables and lines.

Elaboration:

I have a string split by colons (:) and I just want to create a `Set` containing all the :-delimited components excluding the first one.

So that a string "one:two:three" would return a set containing ["two", "three"]. Since I can create a Set from an array, all I really need is to get the suffix of the array, but I don't know how many components there are because it's inline:

```
return Set(attributeName?.componentsSeparatedByString(":").suffixFrom(1))
```

Why does Swift make this so hard?

**Edit:** Before a bunch of you suggest it, I'm well aware I could extend the array class to do this myself, but I'm writing a framework and I don't want to do that, and I also don't want to have to write a bloody utility function to do something so darned simple.

Comment: Who tf downvotes a legitimate question? It's already closed as a dupe ffs. God dammit that makes me angry. Learn some respect people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CollectionType.dropFirst(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FEsPs14CollectionType9dropFirstFSiwx11SubSequence) does exactly what you need, with the exact syntax you're looking for.

```
let suffix = someArray.dropFirst(1)
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I did Google it first I promise!

Comment: For the record, it's pretty hard to find these in the docs because Apple's docs don't show you inherited members

Comment: Swiftdoc (http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/Array/) does include inherited members and the excellent Dash (https://kapeli.com/dash) includes them as well.

Comment: Part of the problem (at least for me) is I find Apple's naming conventions very unintuitive, so I don't even know what to look for.